# Adding a textbox inside each cell of a calendar control in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, calendar

i have added to my page an asp.net calendar control and i would like to add a textbox inside each cell of the calendar, how can i do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to look into the DayRender method of the Calendar control. Then within this you can create a new instance of a TextBox and add it into each day of the controls.

Some Info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender.aspx

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i managed to add a textbox using your suggestion but i was wondering the best way to insert the data throw this textboxes and then retrieve them to the same textbox that was used to insert the data

Comment: You will need to make sure that you run the `DayRender` method and then add the controls before getting their values.